# Does GC remove all objects after ns removal in Clojure?

Tags: clojure, functional-programming, garbage-collection, lisp, clojurescript

I develop some application that it gets data from client and creates new `ns` for it.

After app does some manipulation in `ns`, calling functions etc.

Finally app returns some output and I remove the `ns` afterwards `(remove-ns)`

Does GC remove all data(objects) in that ns?

Another question is: Is to wise to create ns for each client?
I need to isolate clients from each other so there will be no conflict.*(Concurrent users)*

Comment: Attach a profiler an test it out for yourself :)

Comment: Unless you keep references to names or values referenced in the namespace, they are garbage collected. Now, do you really need to have one namespace per client? I don't know. Are you creating fresh symbols for each client?

Comment: @coredump Yep, think like it's new session new environment

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unfortunately there isn't simple yes or no answer to your question.

What `remove-ns`[[1]](https://www.conj.io/store/v1/org.clojure/clojure/1.8.0/clj/clojure.core/remove-ns) does is it calls the static `remove` method in `clojure.lang.Namespace`[[2]](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/master/src/jvm/clojure/lang/Namespace.java#L181), which transactionally unmaps the symbol naming the namespace in the global mapping from ns names to Namespace objects. This makes it impossible to take a new reference to a namespace because namespaces and fully qualified symbols/vars are resolved through the namespace mapping, but it does NOT destroy the namespace or its contents.

If there exist no references to the unmapped Namespace or its contents, then yes it will (eventually) be garbage collected. However this assumes that all the Vars in that namespace never escape. If you ever require/refer Vars from one of these temporary namespaces into a long lived, you're creating a permanent link between the two namespaces which will result in the "temporary" namespace never being removed unless it is also `ns-unmap`ped [[3]](https://www.conj.io/store/v1/org.clojure/clojure/1.8.0/clj/clojure.core/ns-unmap).

Modern JVMs use tracing garbage collectors, so objects will only be garbage collected if there is enough memory pressure to force a GC run, and there are no remaining uses of objects which are not themselves garbage. So for instance if you were compiling a function per-session in its own sandbox namespace, returning that function, calling it and then throwing it away and unmapping the temporary namespace that would *probably* work OK, because the only explicit reference to the temporary namespace is the returned closure (which is discarded) and the global namespace mapping which you remove. But exact behavior depends entirely on the structure of your application.

At an architectural level, it's safe to say you're doing it wrong. Compilation in Clojure (`eval`) is slow. You really shouldn't be dynamically generating functions let alone namespaces at runtime. By doing so, you're creating this architectural problem for yourself because you're (ab)using what's intended to be a global binding structure (Namespaces and Vars) to hold temporary bindings which you then have to worry about cleaning up.

If you really needed dynamic bindings or stack local Vars, there are structures for creating such short-lived context. Otherwise you'd probably simplify your application greatly by refactoring it to make more extensive use of partial application and parametric context, which fall into more normal data use patterns and which will garbage collect normally.

Answer (score 2):

I assume, you're doing `(remove-ns)` on your namespace, so if you look at `clojure.core` in clojure source code, it calls `Namespace.remove` on namespace symbol that in turn gets removed from concurrent hashmap. If symbols are tied only to the namespace, they should be cleaned by gc then.

Have a look at clojure code of the version you're using to be sure, and ofc if you're in doubt at best test it out for yourself by attaching a profiler to see if those objects are in fact removed after this function call.